# High Performance USB connection?

Tags: usb, performance, cpu, controller

I'm wondering if there high performance USB controllers in the same way that there are high performance NIC cards.  I'd like a way to run a USB device with minimal load on the main CPU.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes. It's called "FireWire". *runs*

Comment: ^^ You snuck that in while I was composing my answer!

Comment: Plus 1 for both of you. Hilarious ans SOOOO true!

Comment: If I could somehow take my device apart and solder in a firewire port I would consider that an option. But as it stands I am a consumer and I don't have any control over the ports manufacturers supply in their equipment.

Answer (score 3):

I've not come across any - if high throughput with less CPU load is required, most device manufacturers have traditionally opted for IEEE1394/Firewire/i-link although the range of new interlink types coming out recently (eg: Thunderbolt (formerly Light Peak) etc.) is mind boggling

Ref: http://www.diffen.com/difference/FireWire_vs_USB

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29

Answer (score 0):

I've seen reports that USB performance can be affected by controller chip, but I haven't seen any info on CPU load.

I'll try to dig up some sources now.

For start, there's [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/nec-controller-usb-3-pd720200,2682.html) review.

There are also interesting pages which comment of maximum sustained speed of USB controllers. FOr example, take a look at [these](http://www.plxtech.com/products/net2000/) controllers and speeds on [this](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usb/usbhard2.htm) page. PLX Tech controllers support up to 40 MB/s speeds, while some controllers mentioned at beyondlogic have maximum sustained speed of 12 MB/s.